# How to secure Web API with passport-azure-ad (/w vue-msal)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

I want to secure Web API with passport-azure-ad and use bearerStrategy. I follow the example the module has provided and pass metadata and clientId, I always got 401 unauthorized.

Here is my configs of passport-azure-ad

```
{

  identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your_tenant_guid>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
  
  // Required
  clientID: '<client ID>',

  // Required.
  // If you are using the common endpoint, you should either set `validateIssuer` to false, or provide a value for `issuer`.
  validateIssuer: false,

  // Required. 
  // Set to true if you use `function(req, token, done)` as the verify callback.
  // Set to false if you use `function(req, token)` as the verify callback.
  passReqToCallback: false,

  // Optional. Default value is false.
  // Set to true if you accept access_token whose `aud` claim contains multiple values.
  allowMultiAudiencesInToken: false,

  loggingLevel:'error',
};
}
```

I provided authorization request header with the access token generated by vue-msal.
I also checked the access token's signature is not valid as well. 
In addition, I used ID token instead but still 401 unauthorized.

In portal /AAD /App registration, I've enabled both of implicit grant flow、`accessTokenAcceptedVersion: 2`、granted admin consent for my subscription in API permissions

What else did I missed ?

Comment: That package seems to allow for Bearer token authentication: https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#42-bearerstrategy

Comment: @juunas Thanks, but I see BearerStrategy does not accept any existing bearer token. It acquire token itself .

Comment: Is this what you want? https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#422-use-passportauthenticate-to-protect-resources-or-apis

Comment: @JoyWang It's my fault hadn't read the intro clearly, but I face new issue which is api call with response 302 status. l will update the question description. Thanks

Comment: @JoyWang I updated the question. Hope it is understandable

Comment: Could you provide the code used to get the token?

Comment: @JoyWang Thanks for you attention. I've solved it . The key is the scopes vue-msal has to be passed.

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you could follow this [Use `passport.authenticate` to protect resources or APIs](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#422-use-passportauthenticate-to-protect-resources-or-apis), also make sure you use the correct scope when using vue-msal to get the token.

```
server.get('/api/tasks', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }), listTasks);
```